Add logo to an ERC-20 Token in Safe Wallet?
I'm looking for guidance on how to incorporate a custom logo for the ERC-20 token of the project I work for. Every time I do a transaction It's uncomfortable to have the default logo as I need to double check that I'm transacting with the correct token.
Here are the properties of the token.
proof of legitimacy: https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/autonolas
Network: Ethereum mainnet
contract: https://etherscan.io/token/0x0001a500a6b18995b03f44bb040a5ffc28e45cb0
logo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1odH-fA-XB9ZbDiKH0D4ViAGXM0txdVAg/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for providing this information. Your demand has been correctly forwarded to the corresponding team. They will add it in the next release(s) (unfortunately I cannot give you any estimates of when this will be live); if not we will come back to you here, potentially asking for more information.
Thank you for understanding! Best, Louis

thank you! Best Victor

Thank you for sharing Louis! The update actually occurred, and I realized that I shared a version of the logo with low resolution, could you please share with the relevant team this logo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14R5SYQGXph-g1l2E8p7U0nabtCEY0jYQ/view?usp=sharing  (hi res svg) Sorry for the extra work
